# How to display a new email using outlook and work on the outlook mailn window at the same time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I use MailItem.Display(true) to show up an email i created in a new email windows in Outlook. But the thing is, when the application opens up that new email in a new window, i can't work on the outlook main window until i send the generated new email. how can i get over this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MailItem.Display(false)` to open the window as non-modal, which means that access to the parent window is possible while the child window is open.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861853.aspx